# Requirment is to remove jcombobox along with it's label

Tags: java, swing, spring-boot, jcombobox

How can I hide the `jcombobox` when checkbox `actionperformed` is checked in swing? I tried `setvisible(false)`, but it only hides the dropdown and not its label. How can I hide both, the dropdown and the label?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if (ProtectPointCheckB.isSelected()){
        prodArrayType.setVisible(false);
        // builder.getPanel().remove(arrayTypeJLabel);

        ipSpeed.setVisible(false);
        arrayTypeJLabel.setVisible(false);
        //ipSpeed.removeAll();
        DataPathwaySpeedCombo.setEnabled(true);
        DataDomainModelCombo.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else {
        prodArrayType.setVisible(true);
        ipSpeed.setVisible(true);
        // ...

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if (ProtectPointCheckB.isSelected()){
        prodArrayType.setVisible(false);
        // builder.getPanel().remove(arrayTypeJLabel);

        ipSpeed.setVisible(false);
        arrayTypeJLabel.setVisible(false);
        //ipSpeed.removeAll();
        DataPathwaySpeedCombo.setEnabled(true);
        DataDomainModelCombo.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else {
        prodArrayType.setVisible(true);
        ipSpeed.setVisible(true);
        // ...
```

The code above only hides the dropdown, not the label.

Comment: Can you tell us what object do you intend to hide? We understand it's a JComboBox, but we do not see the definition of any of your variables and methods, except actionPerformed (which is defined twice).

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions. 2) setVisible(false) should be all you need. Post a proper [mcve] demonstrating the problem. That is create a frame with a combo box and a button. When you click the button you invoke setVisible(false) on the combo box. Whole program will be about 20 lines of code to test this specific requirement.

Comment: hi camickr thanks for reply.i m trying to hide jcombobox and its label lets take an example car vill be a jcombobox and drop down list is like lambo,skoda,verna list so, im able to hide drop down list but  not able to remove its tag or label (car) can u tell me any approach

Comment: We do not have a crystal ball, nor psychic powers. You will need to tell us which item you need to hide. We do not know which is your combo box and which is your label. You have not given us any information about the graphic items used in actionPerformed.

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). In this case one card would be a panel holding the label and combo box, the other card would be an empty panel.